# Resizing the HTML table width in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, resize, html-table

I need to vary a `table`'s width after a click event in jQuery.

#### HTML:

```
<table class="zebra" border=0>
```

#### Case 1:

```
$("table.zebra").css("width","600px");
```

#### Case 2:

```
$("table.zebra").css("width","200px");
```

#### CSS:

```
table.zebra{}
table.zebra tr.even td, table.zebra tr.even th { background-color:#FDD017; }
table.zebra tr.odd td { background-color:#FFF380; }
```

This does not change the `table`'s width like I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<table class="zebra">
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('table.zebra').attr('width', 500);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$("table.zebra").width(200);
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/width#val

Comment: still I not able to get Resize the Table width?

Comment: the width() will get the current computed width of the first matched element, according to http://is.gd/9VR3. Not a setter, I think.

Comment: @Sepehr, there is a setter as well .width(val)

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
$("table.zebra").width('200px');
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    $('#MyModalID').find('.modal-dialog').css({
                width: '800px'
            });
```